# attempting Pass or Fail result based on a several cells meeting numeric criteria. "too many arguments for this function"

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-statements, if

Here is the `IF` statement that is generating the error:

```
=IF(B3<=B2, "Pass","Fail", IF(D2>=0, "Pass","Fail", IF(E2>=1,"Pass","Fail", IF(G2>=10.00,"Pass","Fail", IF(H2<=18.00,"Pass","Fail")))))
```

[image: Please See attached for visual]

Comment: You have committed basic mistake that's why getting error,,, !!

Comment: @RajeshS This kind of comments is unhelpful. OP knows that they made some mistake, Excel already told them so. They're asking because they don't know what's the mistake.

Comment: @gronostaj,,, thanks for showing your concern,,, I've shown the correct syntax of the formula,,, and I do believe that being a answerer it's good to be honest & fair,,, OP has to realize all about the basics.  And I've edited my post & included some useful tips to the OP.☺

Comment: @RajeshS This was extremely helpful. Not only to resolve my issue but also educate me on the WHY. I appreciate your time!

Comment: @SamTresidder ,, glad to help you ,,, now you may accept my post as an answer as well Up vote.. keep asking☺

Answer (score 0):

*Try this one.*

**::Edited::**

let me say that why you are getting an error.
You have used formula like,

`=IF(B3<=B2, "Pass","Fail", IF(D2>=0, "Pass","Fail",`

**IF** the logical formula has tow options TRUE & FALSE considering your formula =IF(B3<=B2, "Pass", is the TRUE and "Fail" is FALSE, and once again you put the LOGIC to test IF(D2>=0, "Pass","Fail", actually this should be used as FALSE option.

Check the formula below.

[You may refer this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2#:%7E:text=Use%20the%20IF%20function%2C%20one,another%20value%20if%20it%27s%20false.&text=For%20example%3A,B4-A4%2C%22%22) ,,, [or even this too](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-if-function)

[image]

- Formula in cell J45:

  ```
  =IF(B41<=B40, "Pass", IF(D40>=0, "Pass", IF(E40>=1,"Pass", IF(G40>=10,"Pass", IF(H40<=18,"Pass","Fail")))))
  ```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*